# Rewrite URL to an unknown filename

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I want to add a prefix to URLs as they come through mod_rewrite. I think this is simpler to show in an example than to explain.

Eg, '/my-filename' gets rewritten to '([0-9]+).my-filename'

The possible filenames this would match might include 10.my-filename, 55.my-filename, 123.my-filename, etc...

The 'my-filename' part is guaranteed to be unique. Is this possible with mod_rewrite, or will I have to do it in code?

Thanks,
Andy.

Comment: How is the value of the prefix determined?

Comment: That's the thing. It's arbitrary. The only place it is defined is on the file system, and there's no way of determining it beyond that. I wouldn't be surprised if someone tells me this is just impossible with mod_rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want, you should look at the `RewriteMap` directive of `mod_rewrite`.

It enable you with the rnd format to map a given URL to a random value from a set:

Configuration:

```
##
##  map.txt 
##

static   www1|www2|www3|www4
dynamic  www5|www6
```

and rewriting

```
RewriteMap serveurs rnd:/chemin/vers/fichier/map.txt

RewriteRule ^/(.*\.(png|gif|jpg)) http://${serveurs:static}/$1 [NC,P,L]
RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://${serveurs:dynamic}/$1 [P,L]
```